# error when trying to execute python manage.py migrate

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, django

django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1046, 'No database selected')

I get the above error when I try to execute:

python manage.py migrate

The database settings in my settings.py file are:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'DATABASE': 'financeblog',
        'USER': 'financeblog',
        'PASSWORD': 'xxxxx',
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
        'PORT': '3308',
    }
}
```

I have confirmed that the database does in fact exist. The port is 3308

Comment: I confirmed it with the MySQL cli.

Comment: Connect to your MySql instance and run `SHOW DATABASES;` to see if you have a typo error. And if possible show us an image too.

Comment: Not sure how to show an image here. I do not see a typo

Comment: Can you maybe update your question with the full stack trace of the error?

Comment: It is very long. How can I upload it?/

Answer (score 0):

The keyword DATABASE in settings.py is wrong. Should be NAME

Answer (score 0):

The key for the name of the database is `NAME` (not `DATABASE`). So you should do this:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'financeblog',  # Change this
        'USER': 'financeblog',
        'PASSWORD': 'xxxxx',
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
        'PORT': '3308',
    }
}
```

And make sure, to install the [mysqlclient](https://pypi.org/project/mysqlclient/) python adapter too.

Comment: Yes. I changed it. See my comment. Mysqlclient connector is installed and has been working for months